# How to write rows with similar columns into a new table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to write rows with similar columns[a,c] into a new table df_new and columns [b, d, q] must be saved too.
How to do it?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[13, 2, 13, 4, 13], [4, 13, 4, 7, 13], [6, 5, 6, 10, 15], [6, 2, 6, 10, 15],[6, 8, 6, 10, 15]]),
                   columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'q'])
```

Comment: When you say "similar", do you mean "equal", or some other metric?  What if multiple groups of columns are "similar"? (e.g. `a==c`, `b==d`, `a!=b`) Could you give an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter like this and save to new df

```
new_df = df[df["a"] == df["c"]]
```

or you can make copy to avoid reference

```
new_df = df[df["a"] == df["c"]].copy()
```